# What percentage of human excrement is toxic if ingested?

Tags: digestive-system, toxicology, digestion, gastroenterology, excreta

I have been considering food production, waste management and 3D food printing, particularly during space exploration. This led me to wonder if human excrement could be processed into raw materials for printing healthy food.

What percentage of human excrement is considered toxic to humans if the toxins were ingested in the quantities in which they were excreted? I am referring only to excrement produced by humans not infected with diseases of any kind.

Comment: [The dose makes the poison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dose_makes_the_poison). In other words, everything is toxic, which include all the stuff that you can find in human excrements.

Comment: You can possibly narrow down to - what components of human faeces are toxic at even lower concentrations that should be removed when faeces are to be recycled.

Comment: Do you think that would make it more likely people would look at the question or answer? Only 23 views so far. :/